# Javascript or and assignment operators

Tags: javascript, operators

I was looking through some compiled coffee-script code, and I noticed something like the following, which I thought was really strange:

```
var current, x = 8;
current = this._head || (this._head = x);
```

after running this, current has a value of 8.  Judging by the way that the || logical operator works, I would have expected it to evaluate the left side first.  After getting an 'undefined' on the left hand side, it moves onto the right, where it assigns this._head to 8.  Afterwards it returns a true, but this part isn't that important?  I don't see how it could go back and affect the "current" variable?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: OH!  I just realized I was getting hungup on operator precedence.  The || operator happens before any value has been assigned to current.  I was essentially imagining current = this._head having parentheses around it.  thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` operator returns the *value*, not `true`. Maybe it helps to say that

```
current = this._head || (this._head = x)
```

could also be written as

```
current = this._head ? this._head : (this._head = x);
```

or

```
current = this._head;

if(!current)
    current = this._head = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The `||` operator returns the left hand side if it is "truthy", otherwise, the right hand side -- regardless of its truthiness. It does not *cast* the expression to the boolean true/false!

   - `undefined || (this._head = x)` returns the right hand side
2. The assignment operator also returns a value!

   - `this._head = x` returns 8 in the above example
3. The first assignment operator assigns the value 8 to the variable `current`

Answer (score 0):

You can use expresion

```
var current=this._head ? this._head : (this._head = x);
```